# Any chance to delete python3.7 without affecting anything?

Tags: 16.04, python

I have 2 versions of Python(2.7 and 3.7). I've installed the 3.7 recently and I want to keep just 2.7. After installing 3.7 I had used just

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I've already set my default version as 2.7 using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Can I delete 3.7 without affecting the system?

I want this because I do not want to accidentally use it instead of 2.7.

Please help!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with 2.7 and 3.6 installed by default, and you should keep both of them as they're needed by various applications and system components. If you installed additional Python versions like 3.7 manually from external sources, you can also safely remove them again. Just none that came preinstalled please. Also note that support for 2.7 stops end of this year, so if any of your projects still use Python 2 you should consider migrating them to 3.

Comment: 16.04 comes with 3.5  18.04 comes with 3.6.

Comment: Note that Python 2.7 is going EOL soon: bugfix support for it ends in five months on January 1, 2020, see [PEP 373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases).